# Scraping using simplehtmldom is giving me empty result

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, scrape

I am trying to scrape a website using simplehtmldom but it is giving me an empty result.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');
    ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0");


 echo $html = file_get_html('https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/opt/whey.html');
?>
```

Comment: You may be better off using DOMDocument and loadHTMLFile to load it.

Comment: Do you get any warnings? like `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking`

Comment: No just blank page, you can try it yourself

Comment: I tried and your code works. But if you're using an old version of the library this might be caused by a known bug which is solved in newer versions. Get the library from [here](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) if you're using the original version from SF.